# One-Parameter Group $F:\mathbf{R}\to\text{End}(C^\infty(\mathbf{R}^{2n}))$ Not Generated By Some $\bar F:\mathbf{R}\to\text{End}(\mathbf{R}^{2n})$

Tags: physics, group-actions, poissons-equation, hamilton-equations

Reading [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.14741.pdf) article, and the definition of one-parameter group, I wonder what naturally occuring (in physics or elsewhere) one-parameter groups $\{F_t:C^\infty(\mathbf{R}^{2n})\to C^\infty(\mathbf{R}^{2n})\}_t$ there are which are *not* generated by some $\{\bar F_t:\mathbf{R}^{2n}\to\mathbf{R}^{2n}\}_t$, i.e. of the form $\{g\mapsto g\circ\bar F_t\}_t$.

Here is the relevant section:

> [image]
> [image]